# How to use a string to represent this and use a regexp to test it

Tags: javascript, regex

Here are 2 sets of numbers, from 0 to 9:

```
Set A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
Set B = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```

Pick 1 or more numbers from set A. Pick 2 or more numbers from set B. The numbers we picked from set A and B should be more than 3 and non-repeated. For instance:

picking [ ] from set A and [0, 1, 2] from set B is invalid cause there are 0 number picked from set A.

picking [0, 1] from set A and [1] from set B is invalid cause there are less than 2 numbers picked from set B.

picking [0] from set A and [1, 2] from set B is valid cause there are 0 and 1 and 2 picked.

picking [0, 1] from set A and [1, 2] from set B is valid cause there are 0 and 1 and 2 picked.

picking [0] from set A and [0, 1] from set B is invalid cause there are only 0 and 1 picked. 0 is repeated so there are only 2 numbers picked.

Use a string to represent the number we picked and use a regexp to test that it is valid or not.

Anybody help me? :(

Comment: At first glance this seems very ill-suited for a regexp since there are non-local conditions (for example no repeated numbers) and the regexp would probably have to have **many** different cases. Is there a particular reason why you need this as a regexp?

Comment: @JonathanvonSchroeder Because I've used string and regexp to treat more than 30 cases like this ( in JavaScript). Maybe I will add a case for test it using a function if this question is too difficult. For instance: return (reg instanceof RegExp) ? reg.test(this.toString()) : reg(this.toString());

Comment: If you have full JavaScript at your disposal I see no reason to use regexps at all. Using arrays JavaScript this is much easier. If you want I can show you how to do it.

Comment: Regex isn't the tool to handle stuff like this. Also, you should add the "JavaScript" tag if you are using JS

Comment: @JonathanvonSchroeder The input data has many different types and is passed from another function written by my coworker. It may be 1D or 2D array or a serialized array as a string. That's why I transform it all into string and try to use regexp to test it. :(

Comment: @TheLostMind OK. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to generate a simplified version as given in your question you will have to distinguish these cases anyways. And if you do it should be no more difficult to generate actual arrays (the representation you have shown can be eval'd ...). If you don't care about the arrangement of the dimensions you can simply flatten the multidimensional arrays and unserialize the serialized ones.

Comment: @JonathanvonSchroeder That is a good suggestion. Thank you!

Comment: Here https://jsfiddle.net/yyxwqw1L/3/ is an example of how to write a function to test such simple arrays.